# CakePHP3.7でFriendsOfCakeのインストール時エラー

Tags: php, cakephp

コマンドプロンプトを起動後 `composer require friendsofcake/search` を実行したのですが、下記のようなErrorが出てしまいます。

これは friendsofcake/search のバージョン6.0を使用する場合、CakePHPのバージョンが4系でないといけないということなのでしょうか。今のCakePHP3.7で friendsofcake/search を使用できるようにしたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか。

```
Using version ^6.0 for friendsofcake/search
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for friendsofcake/search ^6.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofcake/search[6.0.0].
    - friendsofcake/search 6.0.0 requires cakephp/cakephp ^4.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.0.0, 4.0.0-RC1, 4.0.0-RC2, 4.0.0-alpha1, 4.0.0-alpha2, 4.0.0-beta1, 4.0.0-beta2, 4.0.0-beta3, 4.0.0-beta4, 4.0.1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6, 4.0.7, 4.0.8, 4.0.9, 4.1.0, 4.1.0-RC1, 4.1.0-RC2, 4.1.0-beta1, 4.1.1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"FriendsOfCake/search" [プラグインの Wiki ページ](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/wiki) にバージョンごとの対応状況が記載されています。

- プラグインの master ブランチ (最新版) = "6.x" については "CakePHP 4.x" の環境が必要。
- "CakePHP 3.x" で使いたいなら、[cake3](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/tree/cake3) ブランチ の "5.x" バージョンを使用すること。
  (リリースページから [5.3.2](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/search/releases/tag/5.3.2) を選んでも良いでしょう)

Comment: モデルクラス(UserTable.php)に$this->addBehavior("Search.Search");を記載して
5.3.2をダウンロードした資材をpluginsフォルダに格納し解凍して処理を実行したら
以下のようなエラーがでました。composer.jsonなど何か修正しないといけないのでしょうか。

search.SearchBehavior could not be found.

Make sure your plugin was loaded from config\bootstrap.php and Composer is able to autoload its classes, see Loading a plugin and Plugins - autoloading plugin classes

Error: Create the class SearchBehavior below in file: C:\省略\plugins\Search\src\Model\Behavior\SearchBehavior.php

Comment: composer require friendsofcake/search:^5.3 のようにバージョンを指定してcomposerでインストールしてください